# VS Code can't recognize interfaces in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm new in vs code and i'm creating a project in asp.net core
I have a class inherited from an interface 
I can build the project and Everything works well 
But vs code shows error red lines under the classes that inherited from interface
The interface and every classes and methods are public
Actually there aren't any errors! only vs code ide thinks there are
How can i fix this bug?
I installed C# extension published by microsoft and debug with .Net Core Launch (web)
[image: help me]

Comment: Does restarting VS Code help? Sounds like something you might want to get help with from the [OmniSharp team](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues)

Comment: wow.. restarting vs code solved that bug, i knew vs studio is more stronger than vs code, but i didn't know how weak vs code is! (another question: how can i set your comment as accepted answer?!)

Comment: You can't, because it's not an answer :) Restarting is not really a solution either, so you may run into the issue again but I suggest you try to check the link if you do.

Comment: i expect the problems like this shouldn't appear now (after published some versions of vs code)

Comment: Bugs (if this is a bug) can come in many forms. No piece of sophisticated software will be bug-free no matter how old it is. Bugs are to be expected, so helping the developers find them is always appreciated :)

Comment: yes i will check your link and hope this bug will fixed soon (of course i think this is a bug)